# adding a link to text attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

Probably a simple question but I need to add a link to the text  as below and I am not sure how to do it

```
callBack: function(me) {
                $(me).text('All done! This is my link to google!').css('color','#090');
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $(me).html($('<a></a>').attr('href','www.google.com')
                           .text('All done! This is my link to google!')
                           .css('color','#090')
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
callBack: function(me) {
  $(me).html('All done! <a href="http://www.google.com">This is my link to google!</a>').css('color','#090');
}
```